# Make input text selected upon appearance in angular

Tags: angularjs

Using angular I have a set of input elements that become present in the dom after a certain user action, i.e I use `ng-if` to determine if it should be present or not. I would like the first of these input elements to gain focus and for the text in it to be selected to that the user easily can change all the content in that element.

Searching the web I have seen several posts that say I should use either the `focus` or `select` method or both but I haven't been able to get the desired result. Here is a directive I created:

```
app.directive('selectMe', function() {
  return function(scope, element) {
    element[0].focus();
    element[0].select();
  };
})
```

And [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/X56s0MsDAnI9ODARVeiw?p=preview) is a plunkr demo. Can anyone tell me why it is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when your directive is initializing, their values isn't attached yet, therefore you should set small `$timeout`.

It works, you can try in plnkr

```
app.directive('selectMe', function($timeout) {
  return function(scope, element) {

    $timeout(function() {
      var ele = element[0];
     ele.focus();
     ele.select();
  }, 500)
```